# Npm error when incuding x-ray-scraper in project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, x-ray

I'm developing an application in Vue, also using the `x-ray-scraper` library, but when I try to run `npm run serve` in the console to view the application locally I get the following error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* _http_common in ./node_modules/http-outgoing/index.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save _http_common
```

Then I tried to run the command `npm install --save _http_common` and again I get an error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for undefined@_http_common.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Without the `x-ray-scraper` library, everything starts up fine, but if I include it in my project, errors appear.
Perhaps the error is related to the version, but I don't understand how to fix it.
My `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "pc-components",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "phantom": "^6.3.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "webpage": "^0.3.0",
    "x-ray-scraper": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you share your package json please

Comment: @rags2riches {
  "name": "pc-components",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "phantom": "^6.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "webpage": "^0.3.0",
    "x-ray": "^2.3.4",
    "x-ray-scraper": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}

Comment: for better readibility, best to add it to your code snippet

Comment: also add to your snippet how you declare and initialise `x-ray`  and `x-ray-scrapper` , since you seem to be using both...

Comment: @rags2riches In my project, I only import `x-ray-scraper` as `import xrc from 'x-ray-scraper'`

Comment: `import * as xrc from x-ray-scrapper` or `import * as xrc from x-ray-scrapper.js`

Comment: please, modify your question by adding the package json and minimal code where you show how you import your modules and how you use that module. Thank you

Comment: what do you mean "thanks for advice", does it work now or you have still some issues?

Comment: @rags2riches of course not your import method is incorrect in Vue

Comment: @rags2riches and this is not related to the import of the module

Comment: it may be related, please try that syntax since it is irrelevant if vue or else

Comment: @rags2riches i tried but the errors remained

Comment: @rags2riches i think something is wrong when i execute `npm install --save _http_common`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225667/discussion-between-rags2riches-and-alexander-morozov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with the import statement, nor are there any issue with the dependencies you have installed.

This is my test:

- npm init into any directory you want
- npm install x-ray-scraper

Then:

```
const x = require("x-ray-scraper");

x('google.com', 'title')
 .then((title) => {
  console.log(title); // Google
});
// logs Google
```

You need a simple backend, even a couple of lines long, in order to initiate the service and use the package.

You can use whatever you like in the front-end, Vue, React, etc.

You do not need any extra dependencies at all from what you already have.

Please [read the docs to see use cases](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray-scraper)